# C# WPF ScrollViewer in UserControl doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need some help with my ScollerViewer. Here is my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ConfigUI.Views.ProfileListView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConfigUI.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="960">
    <Grid Margin="20" Height="500"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <Border ...
       /Border>

       <Border ...  /Border>

       <Border ... /Border>

   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What I want is to show a ScrollBar when this control shows and users can scroll to see the contents.

But now the scrollBar just won't show...

Anybody can help?  Thanks.

Comment: @Clint, tried that. Still not working.

Comment: let me know if the answer below works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `ScrollViewer` on `Grid` directly

Try this structure

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="True">
    <Grid Margin="20" Height="Auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <Border ...
       /Border>

       <Border ...  /Border>

       <Border ... /Border>

   </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks. It still doesn't work.  I finally made it work by changing the Height of the Grid to 1000 then it works.

Comment: Now I know the height of the grid has to be longer than the height of the UserControl.

Comment: set the Height to Auto

Comment: so as the grid grows out of the its container then you would see the scollbar appear